# Display sibling pages via PHP in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know PHP, so this has be stumped.

But what I want is:

For each page with the same parent as current page (so sibling pages) display:

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>
```

But only loop it 12 times.

I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Is that WordPress? if so, tag with "WordPress" tag and you may find more help.

Comment: You just want to loop the above functions 12 times?

Comment: yeh it is wordpress, i added the tag

@GrumpyCrouton 
I want that output 12 times (so for 12 sibling pages) if that makes sense
so parent1->child1 is the one this runs on
i want to display those outputs for parent1-child2/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the parent ID and then get the child posts using that ID. Limit them to 12 posts and exclude current ID. Then iterate over the results.

```
<?php
$parentId = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() );

$children = get_posts( [
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_parent'    => $parentId,
    'post__not_in'   => [ get_the_ID() ] // exclude current page
] );
?>
<ul class="section-nav">
    <?php foreach( $children as $child ): ?>
        <li class="section-nav-item">
            <a href="<?= get_the_permalink( $child->ID ); ?>">
                <?= get_the_title( $child->ID ); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was close to the solution myself, but kept getting stuck on excluding the current post. so "'post__not_in'   => [ get_the_ID() ]" that solved it for me :P